# Slope has gobbled up the retaining walls

Tags: outdoor, stone, retaining-wall, gardening, soil

A few tiered retaining walls were built on a slope on my property about 70 years ago. By now they have been completely consumed by the slope as you can see on the picture below where, in the white bubbles, you can barely see some of the stones.

My question is - can I reclaim the stones for another project without causing problem?

[image]

Comment: should be no problem ... the stones do not appear to be holding anything

Comment: so you're asking if those stones are doing anything important now... it's kind of hard to tell from a photo.